# How to make 3 columns on the desktop and 2 columns on the tablet, with different parent but when on tablet 1 child goes to another parent

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have try it with column but is not work. I want to make column like this in desktop or xl.
[image]

and i want layout like this in lg, it move to left above aside and still sticky
[image]

but in my tries like this in lg. Help me to resolve

[image]

this is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" name="viewport">
  <title>MyPage</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="page">
  <div class="mt-4 container-xl">
  <div class="row">
  <main class="col-12 col-lg-8 order-1 order-lg-2  order-xl-2" id="Main">
  Main content is card
  </main>
  <aside class="col-12 col-lg-4 order-2 order-lg-1">
    aside
  </aside>
  <aside class="col-12 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 order-3 order-lg-2 order-xl-3 sticky-top">
    aside sticky
  </aside>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
 </body></html>
```

Comment: The HTML structure is invalid. Can you edit the question and fix it?

Comment: i fix it, and now i know that is impossible! I tries to switch to bulma because the sample is made by bulma, and evidently the right sidebar is hide in xl and the aside sticky in lg is different from aside sticky! Sory for my bad english, because i tries to write english without translate.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it turned out to be impossible, it's just right no one has answered for the past few days. Now I know it turns out that the sticky aside on the right on xl media is different from the sticky aside on the LG media. The solution is to make two aside sticky one on the left row or the same as the parent aside and must be hidden when the media is xl in size and appears when the media is lg, the other is the aside sticky on the right that has its own parent and will appear only on media with a minimum xl. Of course all that needs to change the size of the column. You can see the example in https://taufik.nurhidayat.web.id